# List all methods that an object respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models,

```
User 
Membership
```

The two have the following relationship with one another

```
user has_many :memberships
```

I've been trying to figure out where the build method resides, and how do i get it in a list of methods for the instance. Here is the output of the debugger that shows my delima

```
(rdb:63) @user.memberships.respond_to?"build"
true
```

While the following is returning false, shouldnt it return true??

```
(rdb:63) @user.memberships.instance_methods.include?"build"
false
```

Comment: you won't be able to see 'build' in a list, it's probably being generated using 'method_missing'

Comment: Is there anyway for me to inspect the method_missing implementation for this? I want to get to the root of how this works

Comment: yes, try running this:

User.new.memberships.method_missing(:build)

you should then see the exception, saying that protected method 'build' was called, then you can try to follow it. But that would need some time

Comment: @user.memberships.method_missing(:build)
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x102fbf8f8>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One point is that `instance_methods` takes an optional boolean parameter, indicating whether you want to see methods of the instances ancestors.  In your case I think you want `instance_methods(true)`.

However, it appears that "build" is an autogenerated method, according to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).  Typically the autogenerated methods in ActiveRecord are implemented by overriding `method_missing` and handling calls to "methods" that don't actually exist.  `responds_to` is also overridden so that the class will indicate that it responds to the correct calls.  However, since those "methods" aren't actually defined, they won't show up in the `instance_methods` list.

Since the list of commands that a class can `respond_to` using `method_missing` is essentially infinite, I'm pretty sure there's no way to get the list.  For example, an ActiveRecord model that has attributes a,b,c, and d will automatically respond to calls such as `find_by_a_and_b` and `find_by_a_b_and_c` and `find_by_b_and_d` and so forth, ad infinitum.  There's no way to get a list of all of those possibilities.

Comment: Didnt work. Output attached (I also tried invoking it on the class rather than the instance per Simone's suggest)(rdb:63) @user.memberships.class.instance_methods(true).include?"build"
false
(rdb:63) @user.memberships.instance_methods(true).include?"build"
false

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
@user = User.first

@user.methods.grep /method_name/
```

However, I don't think you'll see 'build' or 'create' in a list. Most likely these methods are generated dynamically

Answer (score 5):

Please note that `instance_methods` returns an array of String or Symbol depending on the Ruby version.

Ruby 1.8 returns an Array of String, Ruby 1.9 an Array of Symbol.

In Ruby 1.8

```
"".respond_to?(:upcase)
# => true 
"".class.instance_methods.include?("upcase")
# => false
"".class.instance_methods.include?(:upcase)
# => false
```

In Ruby 1.9

```
"".respond_to?(:upcase)
# => true 
"".class.instance_methods.include?("upcase")
# => false
"".class.instance_methods.include?(:upcase)
# => true
```

Also, `instance_methods` must be called on the class, not on the instance.

Comment: Didnt work (rdb:63) @user.memberships.instance_methods(true).include?(:build)
false
(rdb:63) @user.memberships.class.instance_methods(true).include?(:build)
false